# How to access the Query Editor in Beekeeper Studio

Tags: sql, database

Okay, I might be some missing something really obvious. I have recently started using beekeeper studio, its documentation says it has an excellent SQL query editor. But on this entire screen and menubar, I cannot find any button or command to open that query editor. Can someone please point it out to me? The graphics in the documentation are just sufficiently out of date that they don't seem quite applicable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the (+) button to create a new query. Else there's a shortcut, too: ctrl + T

[image]